# Apply a tag to every images 'Link Rel'

Tags: updates

Building my [first site.](http://www.dekho.com.au/)
Running v3.1.1 with the Boldy theme from Site5.

Boldy makes use of [prettyPhoto Lightbox.](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)
If you refer to [the instructions](http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/doc/) for setting up Boldy (bottom of page)

> For adding Lightbox behaviour to a
>   link just add rel="prettyPhoto" to the
>   image Link Rel
>   [image]

I have just imported about 100 blog posts from Wordpress.com.

2 questions (although very related:

1. How do I batch update all previous pictures to load by default with the prettyPhoto
   i.e. Apply a 'prettyphoto' tag to each pictures rel.
2. I have about 15 authors for the blog.  I know they will forget to manually set this prettyPhoto tag = Is there a way to make it default to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `content_filter` that will update on the fly meaning that you don't have to update all previous pictures and it will be the default so you don't have to worry about your authors. something like this:

```
function autoadd_rel_prettyPhoto($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern        = "/(<a(?![^>]*?rel=['\"]prettyPhoto.*)[^>]*?href=['\"][^'\"]+?\.(?:bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)['\"][^\>]*)>/i";
    $replacement    = '$1 rel="prettyPhoto['.$post->ID.']">';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter("the_content","autoadd_rel_prettyPhoto");
```

Comment: sounds perfect.  Im a noob.  Where do I paste this function into?  The functions.php?  I assume it does not matter where in that file?

Comment: yeah, that function needs to be added to your functions.php file

Comment: Sorry did'nt see your comment, yes just copy this code and paste it anywhere in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Can someone help me out. I added this function to my functions.php file of my theme. But the link rel is not applied for images.